# Build own 'Game center' possible?

Tags: ios, game-center

I'm searching through internet, but I haven't found a clear answer.

I'm going to develop a game which, as many games, have score, badges, etc. The question is: can I have my own web page to show this values, with stats, names, leaderboards... or Apple will reject the app if it doesn't use the Apple Game center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t have to use Game Center. There are plenty of games that use other achievement / leaderboard / etc. platforms—Zynga has their own thing, and [OpenFeint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenFeint) was pretty popular for a while.